# Programmatically Change the text of a Combox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, event-handling

I have a user form with a combobox, with 5 unbound data items. The value of each item is of the following format: "## Explanation", a 2-digit numeric code and an explanation of the code. After the user selects an item, I would like to have the 2-digit numeric code displayed only. I have tried the following

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ComboBox1.Text = Mid(ComboBox1.Text, 1, 2)
End Sub
```

However after selecting an item, the assignment doesn't seem to be working properly because `ComboBox1.Text` remains unchanged. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it sounds that you are not really using combo box to full potential. Looks like you want to have items with multiple pieces of info, which you're trying to combine. But here what you can do instead

```
Private Class ComboItem

    Public Property Code As Integer

    Public Property Description As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Display As String
        Get 
            Return Code & " " & Description 
        End Get
    End Property

End Class


Dim lst As New List(Of ComboItem)()
lst.Add(New ComboItem()....) ' add your items

cboList.DataSource = lst
cboList.DisplayMember = "Display"
cboList.ValueMember = "Code"
```

Here where the best part starts - once user selects an item, by typing or clicking, you can do this

```
Dim item As ComboItem = DirectCast(cboList.SelectedItem, ComboItem)
txtCode.Text = item.Code
txtDescription.Text = item.Description
```

I feel, this is what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the value in the combobox's Items collection. If you just change the Text property this is what happens:

[Setting the Text property to null or an empty string ("") sets the SelectedIndex to -1. Setting the Text property to a value that is in the Items collection sets the SelectedIndex to the index of that item. Setting the Text property to a value that is not in the collection leaves the SelectedIndex unchanged.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx)